# How to Route Various domain Aliases to Fetch their Own Folders with Own Webpage PHP Files?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, multilingual

imagine the root of a server where multiple aliases such as website.nl; website.de; etc. all direct to the root the root \httpdocs\ with this physical hosting:

```
httpdocs\...
httpdocs\holland\    # webpages in Dutch   (home.php | contact.php | etc)
httpdocs\deutsch\    # webpages in English (home.php | contact.php | etc)
httpdocs\images\     # all multilingual webpages share the same images
httpdocs\js_css\     # all multilingual webpages share the same scripts/layout
httpdocs\.htaccess   # here be a clean root, nothing else than .htaccess
```

Thus, only the webpages .php differ: the rest they all share the same! Now imagine that you want to configure .htacces via apache script to make "bridge the gap" if you will, between the root and the folder, making it possible to type this in browser and below water fetching the right php webpage, but keeping the shorter url in the browser:

`website.nl/home.php`
//files fetched should come from the holland folder associated with website.nl

`website.de/home.php`
//files fetched should come from the deutsch folder associated with website.de

(As opposed to seeing this in the browser: website.nl/holland/home.php | website.de/deutsch/home.php)

What apache script line will do such thing?
Thanks: Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have "mod_rewrite" installed in apache.
Assuming you do, place a .htaccess file in the root directory of that account
(probably:)
`~/public_html/.htaccess`

and then put this in that file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.nl(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.nl(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ "http\:\/\/www\.website\.nl\/holland\/$1" [L,P]
```

And then repeat the rewrite condition for website.de

Basically that says, grab the section after the website.nl part, and paste it on the part after holland, but the "L,P" says to make that a silent redirect and keep the user on the same url as they entered with.

goodluck!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have full control over the server configuration, I would tend to a setup without mod_rewrite. Instead I'd use two separate `VirtualHost`s for each country site, and `Alias` directives to map the shared directories. In an abridged version, something like this:

```
<VirtualHost website.nl>
DocumentRoot /httpdocs/holland   
ServerName website.nl

Alias /images /httpdocs/images
Alias /js_css /httpdocs/js_css
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost website.de>
DocumentRoot /httpdocs/deutsch
ServerName website.de

Alias /images /httpdocs/images
Alias /js_css /httpdocs/js_css
</VirtualHost>
```

this lets you work freely in both languages, and add new resources and URLs without having to edit anything - only if a shared resource is added, you have to touch the `Alias` directives and restart the server.

Comment: Dear Pekka, Thanks for this elegant solution! Looks clean and clear. However, when I put this in .htaccess, site says **internal configuration error** and error log says: `<VirtualHost not allowed here`... what do I need to have enabled sothat my plesk shared hosting allowes for the VirtualHost directive? Thanks Pekka!

Comment: @Sam this will work only in the central server configuration, not .htaccess - when the .htaccess is processed, the VirtualHost is already defined. If you don't have access to the central config, this won't work (Edit: It's probably not possible with shared hosting - sorry!)